# ViewModel Instantiation Causes Infinite Loop

Tags: android, mvvm, android-viewmodel

I'm using a pattern that I've used a few times before to instantiate a `ViewModel` object. In this case, the data is saved as a string in `SharedPreferences`. I just need to read that string, parse it to the correct object, and assign that object as the value to my view model.

But when I do the assignment, I create an infinite loop.

```
class UserDataViewModel(private val prefs: SharedPreferences): ViewModel() {

    val userData: MutableLiveData<UserData> by lazy {
        MutableLiveData<UserData>().also {
            val userDataString = prefs.getString(Authenticator.USER_DATA, "")
            val ud = Gson().fromJson(userDataString, UserData::class.java)
            userData.value = ud // infinite loop is here
        }
    }

    fun getUserData(): LiveData<UserData> {
        return userData
    }
}
```

This is in `onCreateView()` of the fragment that keeps the reference to the `ViewModel`:

```
userDataViewModel = activity?.run {
            ViewModelProviders
                 .of(this, UserDataViewModelFactory(prefs))
                 .get(UserDataViewModel::class.java)
            } ?: throw Exception("Invalid Activity")

userDataViewModel
    .getUserData()
    .observe(this, Observer {
        binding.userData = userDataViewModel.userData.value
    })
```

FWIW, in the fragment, I have break points on both `getUserData()` and on `binding.userData...`. The last break point that gets hit is on `getUserData()`.

I don't see where the loop is created. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `userData` field is only initialized once the `by lazy {}` block returns. You're accessing the `userData` field from within the `by lazy {}` block and that's what is creating the loop - the inner access sees that it hasn't finishing initializing, so it runs the block again..and again and again.

Instead, you can access the `MutableLiveData` you're modifying in the `also` block by using `it` instead of `userData`, breaking the cycle:

```
val userData: MutableLiveData<UserData> by lazy {
    MutableLiveData<UserData>().also {
        val userDataString = prefs.getString(Authenticator.USER_DATA, "")
        val ud = Gson().fromJson(userDataString, UserData::class.java)
        it.value = ud
    }
}
```

Comment: Makes perfect sense. Thanks!

Comment: Yes also solved my problem which had the same origin.